# Model.create does not create document, but is resolved as a promise

Tags: node.js, post, mongoose

So im trying to practice making routes, and using a mongodb database, and I stumbled upon this problem:

Whenever I try to make a document, regardless if it is validable or not (yes I made that up), it always brings up success, but does not show the new document, nor put in the database. Here is what I comes up in postman:

also, I am basically directly copying off a udemy course, except with different schema and model names.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {}
}
```

this is in my schoolController.js:

```
exports.createSchool = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newSchool = await School.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        school: newSchool,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "error",
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

here is the schoolModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A school must have a name"],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "public school",
    trim: true,
  },
  teacherCount: {
    type: Number,
    min: [1, "There must be atleast one teacher"],
  },
  streetName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, "A school must have a street name"],
  },
  ratingsAverage: {
    type: Number,
    min: [0, "Minimum rating is 0"],
    max: [5, "Maximum rating is 5"],
  },
  studentCount: {
    type: Number,
    min: [1, "A school must have at least one student"],
  },
  builtOn: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "A school must have a build date"],
  },
});

const School = mongoose.model("School", schoolSchema);

module.exports = School;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you connect to database with mongoose?

this is how I usually use it. user.validate() is going to throw error if it's not valid as Schema said and your try catch block will catch it or you can put `then` and  `catch` and act in place.

```
const newSchool = new School(req.body);
await user.validate();
await user.save();

res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        school: newSchool,
      },
    });
return;
```

Comment: yeah I connected with mongoose, but also, my instructor didn't need to use .save() and .validate(), it just worked for him.

Comment: @Tidris Yeah that's a shortcut. but try this also and at least you see where issue can be.

Comment: I think I figured out what the main problem is, the promise gets resolved, but it does not create a file.

Comment: I had the same problem with  .Create that's the reason actually I use this way.